# Pointers/C-Strings in C++. How to filter the strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c-strings

I have an array to filter.

**Example:**

`str = "hellothere"` and `filter = "eo"`. What to do when i need to filter?

```
void filter_str(char* str, char* filter, char*result)
{
  while(*str)
  {
       if() //If the current character in str is one to be filter. 
        {
                 *str++;
        }
        else
        {
                *result++ = *str++;
        }

 } 
 *result = '\0';
}
```

I just can't figure out how to check if the current character is one that needs to be filter. Since the filter can be more than one character, such as "eo". How do I check both "e" and "o" every loop, and then reset filter back to "e" at the start.

I wanted to make a pointer to the start of filter, then use that at the end of the while to go back to the start of filter. But I am not sure how to make it check *str against all the characters to be filtered.

Comment: Is it necessary that you use c strings?

Comment: Yep. But with all this help I think I figured it out.

Comment: A question: is that the function declaration given to you, that is, is result supposed to be pre-allocated buffer? Or did you decide that yourself, it's not pre-defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case a function has already been written that will do the hard work for you

```
if (strchr(filter, *str))
```

In general this is the answer to any question where you have processing that is too complex for you to handle. Write a function to solve the 'inner' problem, and then use that function in  the 'outer' problem. In this case the inner problem is finding a character in a string, and the outer problem is the filtering operation you are doing. You are just lucky that the inner problem has already been solved for you.

Comment: This question is a practice test for my exam. On the real exam, we can only use functions we write our self, so i can't use that, sorry! Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user1767422 OK like I said above, write that function for yourself! Call it something different however.

Comment: int my_strchr (char * filterstr, char c) { for (char* p = filterstr; *p != 0; ++p) if (*p == c) return 1; return 0; }

Comment: What is the advantage to using ++p vs p++?

Comment: @user1767422: In this case there is no advantage since `p` is a pointer (i.e. a built-in type). But it is a good idea to get used to preincrement (`++p`) instead of postincrement (`p++`) whenever you don't need the return value, since it is usually faster for user types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a letter is in `filter`, the "easy" way (without using STL functions) would be to loop through the elements of `filter` and check each one of them to see if you find the character you are looking for.

```
while(*str)
{
    bool found = false;
    // For each element in filter {
        // If *str == element {
            found = true;
            break; // This function gets you out of the 'for' loop
        }
    }

    if(found) //If the current character in str is one to be filter. 
    {
```

You can fill up the pseudocode in comments